# Principal on gaining more height based on nested poles?

Tags: design

How do people design *height gaining* based on nested poles ?

Consider this picture (I made them) :
[image]

If I want to achieve height based on these 3 poles, how they should behave?

Is this how the behave?

[image]

I had been searching over the internet I haven't found the related material, and it's kinda hard what to type. I'm doing some tasks on designing a simple robot (no foundation knowledge but with will) and my English is sort of limited, especially to technical stuff but I hope you understand it .

*Imagine like there's somehow an auto increasing portable stair to get over the tree, the poles(both sides) are consisted of  poles fragment on each of them, how the fragments behave in this case.